Bash script for opening multiple terminal tabs in Windows Subsystem for Linux
I need a bash script that opens multiple terminal tabs when executed.
Each of these tabs should also "cd" into a specific folder.
This is the script that works in Linux, but as expected, in Windows with WSL it doesn't work and it throws the following error: "gnome-terminal: command not found".
#!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal --tab -- bash -c "cd /home/$USER/folder1; exec bash"
gnome-terminal --tab -- bash -c "cd /home/$USER/folder2; exec bash"

How should I change the script in order to work with WSL in Windows?
Note: WSL version I'm using is: 2.2.4

What terminal are you using for WSL? Are you using "Windows Terminal" or some other Windows program or something Linux-based via WSLg?

Why not just execute the scripts instead of opening a bash that execute the script ?

@grawity_u1686 I'm using "Windows Terminal".
If I run the script from Ubuntu terminal (in Windows with WSL) I get the error "gnome-terminal: command not found".
I would be fine with running the script directly from the WSL ubuntu terminal.
